# Video en un div al 100%

Tags: video-adaptativo

Necesito poner en un div al 100% de alto y ancho del navegador un vídeo.

No me sirve la propiedad de ccs3 cover, ya que cuando se hace "resize" no queda bien enmarcado si el navegador es muy pequeño.

He pensando en usar el evento .scroll() para que coja las dimensiones del navegador y del video y según la resolución se adapte.

Quiero usar algo similar a esto:

[bigvideo](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-simple.html)

Pero por otro lado, lo quiero hacer manual, ya que lo que quiero hacer con ese plugin hay cosas que no me permite y ya llevo unos días peleandome sin resultado, llegando a ser frustrante y por eso mismo, cuando haces algo manual desde cero, es mas controlable.

Muchas gracias a todos !!!!

Comment: ¿Quieres que se quede de fondo el vídeo? en tu página web?

Comment: Si, la idea es poner unos cuantos videos con botones de next y previous... pero eso ya lo tengo controlado. Lo que me falla es que el video dentro de un div de quede con ese efecto.  Saludos